# Check all in filter dropdown antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, antd, ant-design-pro

is it possible with antd table to add a "check all" button in the filter list that can work in two ways:

check all options if there is no filtred items (filterSearch: false or user didnt type in search input)
check all filtered options if there is a filter in the filters (when filterSearch:true)

Answer (score 0):

check here https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/discussions/32565

in the official gitlab repository of ANTD.

Comment: Welcome to SO. A link only answer is not acceptable. It is always better to give a glimpse of the solution or context present to which the link is pointing to.